# JavaScript replace string and comma if comma exists else only the string

Tags: javascript

I got a string like:

```
var string = "string1,string2,string3,string4";
```

I got to replace a given value from the string. So the string for example becomes like this:

```
var replaced = "string1,string3,string4"; // `string2,` is replaced from the string
```

Ive tried to do it like this:

```
var valueToReplace = "string2";
var replace = string.replace(',' + string2 + ',', '');
```

But then the output is:

```
string1string3,string4
```

Or if i have to replace `string4` then the `replace` function doesn't replace anything, because the comma doens't exist.

How can i replace the value and the commas **if the comma(s) exists**?
If the comma doesn't exists, then only replace the `string`.

Comment: can string2 be first or last? Or is it always in the middle?

Comment: It can be anywere.

Comment: @Red Your string may have duplicates ?

Comment: `string.split(',').filter(s => s !== 'string2').join(',');`

Comment: No, they are unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modern browsers

```
var result = string.split(',').filter( s => s !== 'string2').join(',');
```

For older browsers

```
var result = string.split(',').filter( function(s){ return s !== 'string2'}).join(',');
```

First you split string into array such as `['string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4' ]`

Then you filter out unwanted item with [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). So you are left with `['string1', 'string3', 'string4' ]`

`join(',')` convertes your array into string using `,` separator.

Comment: I know I wrote exactly this as a comment, but to be a good answer, it should really include an explanation of how it works.

Comment: It works, one more question. Whats the oldschool `JavaScript` version of this one? In IE this doens't work..

Comment: Which version of IE is the minimum acceptable version for you?

Comment: @Phylogenesis 9

Comment: Then something like `string.split(',').filter(function (s) { return s !== 'string2'; }).join(',');` should work?

Comment: @Phylogenesis Nice one! it works for all browsers. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, just note that [`Array#filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Browser_compatibility) does not exist in IE8, so it won't work there.

Comment: but IE9 is fine

Comment: Yes, minimum is IE9. Nice oneliner, short and simple :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Split the string by comma.
You get all Strings as an array and remove the item you want.
Join back them by comma.

```js
var string = "string1,string2,string3,string4";
var valueToReplace = "string2";
var parts = string.split(",");
parts.splice(parts.indexOf(valueToReplace), 1);
var result = parts.join(",");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to replace one of the two commas not both, so :

```
var replace = string.replace(string2 + ',', '');
```

Or :

```
var replace = string.replace(',' + string2, '');
```

You can check for the comma by :

```
if (string.indexOf(',' + string2)>-1) {
    var replace = string.replace(',' + string2, '');
else if (string.indexOf(string2 + ',', '')>-1) {
    var replace = string.replace(string2 + ',', '');
} else { var replace = string.replace(string2,''); }
```

Comment: Yes, but what if ive to replace `string4`? then the comma doens't exist at the end and the `replace` doenst replace anything.

Comment: You can check as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace only 1 comma and also pass the correct variable to replace method such as

```js
var string = "string1,string2,string3,string4";
var valueToReplace = "string2";
var replaced = string.replace(valueToReplace + ',', ''); 
alert(replaced);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the string and check after that for the comma

```
var replace = string.replace(string2, ''); 
if(replace[replace.length - 1] === ',')
{
    replace = replace.slice(0, -1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "string1,string2,string3"
tmp = []
match = "string3"
str.split(',').forEach(e=>{
    if(e != match)
        tmp.push(e)
})
console.log(tmp.join(','))
```

okay i got you. here you go.

Comment: What if its last item?

Answer (score 0):

You can use string function replace();

eg:

```
var string = "string1,string2,string3,string4";
var valueToReplace = ",string2";
var replaced = string.replace(valueToReplace,'');
```

or if you wish to divide it in substring you can use substr() function;

```
var string = "string1,string2,string3,string4";
firstComma = string.indexOf(',')
var replaced = string.substr(0,string.indexOf(','));
secondComma = string.indexOf(',', firstComma + 1)
replaced += string.substr(secondComma , string.length);
```

you can adjust length as per your choice of comma by adding or subtracting 1.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is - **How can i replace the value and the commas if the comma(s) exists?**

So I'm assuming that `string` contains spaces also.

So question is - how can we detect the comma existence in `string`?

Simple, use below Javascript condition -

```js
var string = "string1 string2, string3, string4";
var stringToReplace = "string2";
var result;

if (string.search(stringToReplace + "[\,]") === -1) {
  result = string.replace(stringToReplace,'');
} else {
  result = string.replace(stringToReplace + ',','');
}

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
```